# Leaflet SVG overlay random blur

Tags: image, svg, leaflet

I am using Leaflet to overlay SVGs on top of the map. These SVGs are positioned to exactly overlay on a location such that it covers it perfectly. Think of overlaying a running track with a custom SVG.

To overlay, I am using L.imageTransform as I need to transform them. L.imageTransform extends L.imageOverlay to overlay the image (should I use SVG overlay, not sure?)

The problem is, on some of the overlays, when I zoom in, the SVG gets blurry and it loses its detail that we want. Blurry locations differ in Firefox and Chrome, and are randomly blurred. A sample blurred image can be seen below:

[image]

This could either be a browser issue or could be due to the scaling of map tiles. Any ideas?

Comment: Browsers often scale, rotate and translate SVG's on the GPU - which means that they're rasterized and converted to pixels before they're transformed. This produces the blur on zoom-in. There are two fixes - one is avoid using transforms (if Leaflet uses them, then you're out of luck.) The other is to tack on non-GPU'able CSS to your SVG to keep it out of the GPU's sticky fingers. The latter is unpredictable & hacky but sometimes works.

Comment: Thanks, I avoided transformation and since I only needed to rotate my SVGs, I used a very handy leaflet plugin [here](https://github.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.ImageOverlay.Rotated)